# Combine multiple Selects without Union or Union All

Tags: mysql

I had a massive query that used to perform UNION ALL on a lot of tables (each with thousands of rows) and then outputs to a temporary table before returning it.

Old form:

```
 SELECT *
FROM   (SELECT `a` AS `Human readable A`,
               `b` AS `Human readable B`,
               `c` AS `Human readable C`,
        FROM   `table1`
        UNION ALL
        SELECT
               `a` AS `Human readable A`,
               `b` AS `Human readable B`,
               `c` AS `Human readable C`,
        FROM   `table2`
        UNION ALL
        SELECT
              `a` AS `Human readable A`,
              `b` AS `Human readable B`,
              `c` AS `Human readable C`,

        FROM `table3`
) AS temp_table
```

This query pretty much killed the database (query takes anywhere between 20 minutes and 61 minutes), over which time the CPU is completely maxed out.

I discovered that **running an individual SELECT statement for each table only took a few seconds** at most, and decided to merge them together on the application level which rests on a different physical server which is an added bonus (pseudocode below).

```
    $result1 =  SELECT
                      `a` AS `Human readable A`,
                      `b` AS `Human readable B`,
                      `c` AS `Human readable C`,

                FROM `table1`

    $result2 =  SELECT
                      `a` AS `Human readable A`,
                      `b` AS `Human readable B`,
                      `c` AS `Human readable C`,

                FROM `table2`

    $result3 =  SELECT
                      `a` AS `Human readable A`,
                      `b` AS `Human readable B`,
                      `c` AS `Human readable C`,

                FROM `table3`

$result4 = merge($result1, $result2, $result3)
```

However, I feel that this is slightly unsafe because a query may update the data in-between these separate select queries. **Is there a way to improve my set of select statement queries such that it gets treated as just one transaction** (no writes needed) so all the data will be locked with a shared read lock and returned.

**Additional info**

I predict that the original form took far longer because it was spending a lot of CPU time re-creating/sorting the indexes in the combined table, something I do not need to do (I only need to append the results together).

- All the tables have the exact same structure
- Please note there are about 34 of `a` AS `Human readable A` per table, Data was separated into different tables because they relate to different projects.
- There are 20 unions in this particular query (21 tables).
- Using InnoDB tables for the data. I know this is more intensive on the CPU than MyIsam, but after reading about the various drawbacks of MyIsam, I am unwilling to switch storage engines.
- There are no WHERE clauses (data already "pre-grouped" by having been split into tables)

Comment: Show us (a cutdown version of) the query

Comment: Do you have any filtering or order by going on? If so, that might be the issue, because MySQL needs to order the total results, while not being able to use any indexes. If you just combine all tables using `union all` this should be very fast, when there is no sorting or filtering going on.

Comment: @GolezTrol I dont believe I have any filtering or ordering going on. I made sure to use UNION ALL instead of UNION as I beliew without the ALL it would performe a sort/search for duplicates.

Comment: I can't believe I'm suggesting this - but if each individual select only takes a few seconds, why not just combine them at the application level? It's going to reduce query time to three or four minutes at most.

Comment: @Bohemian I have updated the question with the query structure for you.

Comment: @Strawberry thats what I've done, Im just wondering if it can be improved with a single transaction read lock or something? "Is there a way to improve my set of select statement queries such that it gets treated as just one transaction (no writes needed) so all the data will be locked with a shared read lock"

Comment: The point about separating them because they are separate projects just doesn't make sense. If they all hold the same kind of information, then they should all be in the same table.

Comment: @Strawberry I completely agree, however this is the database structure I have been fed/given and not allowed to change any time soon.

Comment: Pity. Changing it would MASSIVELY improve all aspects of information management and query performance.

Comment: @Stu2000 Can you remove the `SELECT * FROM (...) AS temp_table` and run the part in the `...` itself?

Comment: You could also try creating a temp table, and doing multiple queries each inserting to that temp table.

Comment: It would be helpful if you add a summary of what you're after.  In its current form your question is attracting close votes due to being unclear.

Comment: Are there any "where" conditions?

Comment: @DoctorJones I have tried to clean up the question to make things clearer and boldened the two main points that form the actual question.

Answer (score 0):

Considering your constraint, the best call would be locking the tables explicitely before issuing each successive `SELECT`:

```
SET autocommit=0; -- optional, but this is where and how you must start the transaction if you need one
LOCK TABLES t1 READ, t2 READ, t3 READ;
SELECT a FROM t1;
SELECT a FROM t2;
SELECT a FROM t3;
UNLOCK TABLES; -- beware: implicit COMMIT
```

Unless there is some kind of legal requirement to keep this data in several tables, you really should insist on validating merging all these tables into one single table.

Comment: I think this might be the answer (whilst tables are separate). Could you please clarify why beware implicit commit. Would it not be safer just to add COMMIT before this statement? Also, why is begin transaction optional, surely it is required?

Comment: 1. `UNLOCK TABLES` commits the current transaction (if started), so you might be committing a transaction unknowingly. 2. If your "transaction" does not read from any other table, then a real transaction is superflous, because `LOCK TABLES` actually provides *more* isolation than a regular transaction (the whole table is locked). 3. I made a mistake in the workflow, please check my update.

Comment: Reading from http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/commit.html it sounds like what I really want is: START TRANSACTION WITH CONSISTENT SNAPSHOT; (innodb only), then the select queries followed by COMMIT at the very end with no table locking. Although in this unique case, since I want the entire table in each table, locking the entire table is probably faster (prevent innodb locking every row)?

Comment: I just ran a test and this now causes a 13 percent cpu spike instead of a 9.5% spike that running LOCK Tables did so using TRANSACTION WITH CONSISTENT SNAPSHOT looks like it is more cpu intensive, but may be better as I am not read locking the entire table? Either way in both cases Im not using 100% for many minutes as I did with the UNIONS.

Comment: This allows concurrent access to the tables at the cost of increased CPU usage (logical: as a full flavoured transaction, it requires more plumbing maintenance). This is an interesting alternative that I didn't know was possible.

Answer (score 0):

I thought I would provide two possible solutions and their various benefits through a code sample. One of the solutions is 'stolen' from RandomSeed's answer:

```
if ($READING_ONLY_INNODB_TABLES)
{
    /**
     * - Since these tables are innodb, we can make use of its 'REPEATABLE READ'
     * isolation level
     * - Locking the entire tables directly is slightly faster, but this method 
     * allows us to have a consistent view of the database without implementing
     * ANY locks (which would block other processes). 
     * It may be easier to think of them as locking as this results in the same 
     * result in terms of consistency (innodb even handles phantom reads at this level)
     * - MyIsam does not support REPEATABLE READ, hence this cannot be used for it
     */
   $query = 
       'START TRANSACTION WITH CONSISTENT SNAPSHOT;'. # --auto sets "SET autocommit=0"
       $queries_string . # --This is the series of selects
       'COMMIT;';
}
else
{
    /**
     * This is a lower resource intensive, 'generic' way (works with MyISAM) that will wait until it can read lock
     * all the tables before reading. This way we should 'force' a 
     * 'repeatable read'/consitent view.
     */
    $query = 
        'SET autocommit=0;'. # starts the transaction
        'LOCK TABLES ' . $lock_tables_string . ';' . # Automatically commits anything before this
        $queries_string . # This is the series of selects from the tables we just locked
        'UNLOCK TABLES;'; # commits a transaction if any tables currently have been locked with LOCK TABLES    
}
```